# How do I sort a java text file so that I can obtain the median?

Tags: java, file, median

I have the code below so far. I know the median is wrong because I've placed numbers in it and what I really want is for the program to extract these from the file on its own since the numbers may change. I am not sure how to have the program get the 2 numbers in order to retrieve and calculate the median. Please help. I am very new to this and it has taken me all day to get this far!

```
    package trials;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;

public class trials2 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    // This is a Scanner object that reads from the keyboard
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    // The following is set to find the file
    System.out.println("Please enter the name of your data file: ");
    String fileName = in.next();

    // The file is then to be scanned
    Scanner fileToRead = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

    // This loop finds the contents within the file
    double sum = 0;
    int numStudents = 0;
    double maxVal = 0, minVal = 0;
    boolean bFirstTime = true;
    double currVal;
    while (fileToRead.hasNext()) { 
        if (fileToRead.hasNextDouble()) {
            numStudents++;
            currVal = fileToRead.nextDouble();

            // The following will find the maximum and minimum values within the file
            if (bFirstTime) {
                maxVal = currVal;
                minVal = currVal;
                bFirstTime = false;
            } else {
                maxVal = Math.max(maxVal,currVal);
                minVal = Math.min(minVal, currVal);
            }

            sum += currVal;
        } else {
            fileToRead.next();
        }   
    }
   // Prints out comments and results
   System.out.println("***Welcome to the Exam Statistics Program!!***");
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Minimum = " + minVal);
   System.out.println("Maximum = " + maxVal);   
   System.out.println("Average score: " + sum/numStudents);
   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Number of scores by letter grade: ");
   System.out.println();       
   System.out.println("There are " + numStudents + " scores");
}
}
```

Comment: Why dont you sort it using `merge or quick sort` and then getting the min, max, avg, total etc would be really easy. Working: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort.

Comment: It might be better to store your numbers in a data structure, like a `List`, so that you could sort it easier, and have the ability to find the median easier.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few steps to doing this.

1. At the beginning of your program, create an `ArrayList<Double>` for storing your values in.
2. Within your main loop, use the list's `add` method to add each value as you read it.
3. At the end of your loop, Use `Collections.sort` to sort your list.
4. Use the following logic to work out the median.

   - If the size of the list is zero, then there's no median.
   - If the size of the list is odd, then the median is the value at position `size() / 2` of the list.
   - If the size of the list is even, then the median is the average of the value at position `size() / 2 - 1` and `size() / 2` of the list.

I deliberately haven't given you code, because I think you're enjoying learning how to do this for yourself.  But feel free to post a comment if you need more detail on any particular step.

Comment: Thank you David! I've only been able to paste this into my code so far. I couldn't figure out the rest :-/

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File("filepath"));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while (s.hasNext()){
    list.add(s.next());
}
s.close();

Comment: Oh, don't make an `ArrayList<String>`.  Use an `ArrayList<Double>` instead.  After the line where you do `currVal = fileToRead.nextDouble();`, add `currVal` to your list.

Comment: Thank you David for the continuous help. I fell asleep on my computer :/ I'm heading to work now but will continue this when I return. My professor will take 10% off the grade as I will be turning it in late :/ but at least I will get to become more familiar with the language. It is comforting to know I have people so willing to guide me :)

Comment: You're welcome.  You'll find that the Stack Overflow community is full of very capable people who are more than happy to help out.